# What pretrained word embeddings does the Universal sentence encoder use for Deep Averaging Network?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, word-embeddings

The paper for Universal sentence encoder [Universal sentence encoder paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11175.pdf)! is pretty straightforward, and so is the paper for Deep averaging network [Deep averaging network paper](https://aclanthology.org/P15-1162.pdf)! but I'm confused about one thing in Universal sentence encode, what's the embeddings they've used for the Deep averaging network! seems like they never talked about it on the paper! was just wondering what pre-trained embeddings they have used for the Deep Averaging network,pre-trained embeddings they have used for their transformer, or what embeddings the Universal Sentence Encoder-Lite demo is using for DAN? Does anyone know what embeddings they might be using?

Comment: You may have better luck by specifically citing/linking the papers you refer to.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy just did that!

Comment: I don’t see any indication in the first paper that their word embeddings are pre-trained.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thank you so much for your response! You're right they never made mention of pre-trained word embeddings but don't you need pre-trained word embeddings for a Deep averaging network and the transformer architecture they mentioned in the paper? I'm confused about how they generated embeddings if they did not use pre-trained word embeddings

Comment: Why wouldn’t they just learn them?